# Is there a common word in use for fields and properties?

Tags: c#, .net, naming

Very often I need to name generated methods which operate on both fields and properties with the same intention of setting it. Is there a word that covers both of these terms?

Comment: "Class members" ;) Being serious - why do you want to mix it? It's pretty different things, and I don't think mixing them is a good idea.

Comment: @AndyKorneyev ["Member" includes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645622(v=vs.71).aspx) methods, events, constructors, nested types, etc.

Comment: Are you looking for the word "Member"?

Comment: @AndyKorneyev Instance member is the more appropriate word. Class member could mean static member.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel - I need to narrow it down, a method is a member too.

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: @AndyKorneyev - It is part of an ORM, if you are familiar with that, then it may all make sense now.

Comment: @toplel32 Well, a `Property` is effectively a `Method`. get and set methods ;)

Comment: Somehow the word "state" seems to be a focus point.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel - I need a name thats based on the semantics of the language, not the IL representation.

Comment: I don't think a widely used term exists. You may have to come up with one - i'd suggest "data member" for fields/properties/indexers. Other members tend to define behaviour, not data/state.

Comment: I would call `Data members`. You can look at [DataMemberAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datamemberattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) they only applied to `Properties` and `Fields`

Comment: @dcastro Properties can define behaviour too because of possible side effects in setters.

Comment: @AndyKorneyev - That would be an implementation detail, from the standpoint of an ORM, these details do not matter. What matters is that I have a member, and I can change the data covered by the member, for that I need a common term.

Comment: @AndyKorneyev Good practices dictate that properties should not have any *observable* side effects. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20195519/857807).

Comment: I think I'll go with 'DataMemberMutator'.

Answer (score 1):

The word is 'Member'.

If you use reflection to get properties, fields, or methods on a class you get: PropertyInfo, FieldInfo and MethodInfo instances. All of these inherit from MemberInfo.

Comment: Thats right, but read the comments.

Comment: They are generally called members: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173113.aspx

Comment: @Ananke - Yes, you are right, but OP is looking for a term that includes fields and properties, but excludes methods and everything else. So my vote would also go to DataMember.